# What is the geographic term for a landmass separated by two rivers?

Tags: geography

If there is a region of land that sort of makes an island with the two rivers (which are fare apart). What would you call it.

For Example there is a region in Iraq/Syria that almost forms this (the rivers don't connect)
You can find it near the cities:Ramadi,Haditha,Qa'im,Deir ez-Zur....
Found from around 42.82E,6.61N to 43.26E,33.44N to 40.41E,35.14N to 40.85E,36.4N

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, your coordinates are incorrect: 42.82E, 6.61N is in Ethiopia.

Comment: @MarkBeadles If you look at the other coordinates, it is easy to see that the 6.61N coord is a typo for 36.61N.

Comment: The obvious latinate version, [interfluve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfluve), seems to be rather more particular than just 'the general area between two rivers', or [interamnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interamnia) which seems to be particular to geographical areas near Rome.

Answer (score 4):

That particular example is well-known in English as ***[Mesopotamia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesopotamia)***, from Ancient Greek Μεσοποταμία "between rivers". Mesopotamia can also be used in an extended sense to refer to other similar areas:

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117052?redirectedFrom=mesopotamia#eid):

> 1. In the names of places likened in some way to Mesopotamia. An area of land between two rivers. Also in extended use.